# wrapping C++ to Python with Swig on Mac OS X

Tags: python, c++, swig

I am trying to wrap simple c++ code by swig for python. My code is
`hello.cpp`

```
#include <iostream>
/*simple function for trying swig*/
char const* greet(){
    return "hello world!";
}
```

wrapper code `helloworld.i`

```
/*interface file for swig : corresponds to hello.cpp*/
%module helloworld
%{
/*headers and declarations here*/
extern char const* greet();
%}
extern char const* greet();
```

The commands I used :

```
swig -c++ -python helloworld.i
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c hello.cpp
g++ -O2 -fPIC -c helloworld_wrap.cxx -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
g++ -lpython -dynamclib hello.o helloworld_wrap.o -o _helloworld.so
```

The first three commands work well and produce all the files needed but the last command gives the following error.

Error message:

```
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-dynamclib'
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see     invocation)
```

What is going wrong here? I am very confused with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `-dynamiclib` instead of `-dynamclib`.

EDIT (answering your comment below):

I can reproduce the error

```
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

if I try to import the module from a different python than it was linked against.

You are linking against the system python, so you should use that. Try:

```
/usr/bin/python
>>> import helloworld
>>> helloworld.greet()
```

Probably you have another python version installed somewhere. Do `which python` to see which version is being called.

Now, to link against the correct python, you can either use `python-config` to determine the correct compiler arguments, or write a small `setup.py` file and let distutils handle the compilation (probably the best way to go).

Comment: hey great thanks, it created the library :D  but then i have another error. When I try to import the library in python now i get : `Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6`

Comment: hey this is great, it finally works. i used `/usr/bin/python` and it imported fine and function `greet()` worked fine. when I do `which python` i get `//anaconda/bin/python`, this is the problem as you rightly said. i am very new at this, can you suggest me how should i go with writing small `setup.py` to handle this situation? your help has been great. thank you very much :)

Comment: also, i want to later work with importing wrapped functions from C++ to python by using ipython or spyder through anaconda, so it would be better if I just link against the python from anaconda? so basically would doing this work for it ? `g++ -O2 -fPIC -c helloworld_wrap.cxx -I//anaconda/bin/python`

Comment: You should link against the python that you actually want to use. For this you need the location of the header files and the library. That is what the python-config utility is for. The distutils (or setuptools) handles compilation of c++ extensions and also swig nicely. Just have a look at the documentation, or google for `distutils c++ extension swig`. I think even the swig docs have a basic example for this.

Comment: I tried linking against the anaconda python `g++ -O2 -fPIC -c helloworld_wrap.cxx -I//anaconda/include/python2.7` pointing to where the location of header files are. but still i get the same error `Fatal Python error`. I did not find any guide on using of `python-config` also the `--help` option does not give anything out. i googled the `disutils c++ extension swig` but did not find much information that i could use.

Comment: `-I...` is for header file search path, `-L...` is for library search path, `-l...` is for libraries to link. This is basic stuff.

Comment: hey, yeah sorry I am a beginner to this and not really a computer science guy, so i am completely lost here. I am checking out the disutils link you sent but i still feel lost. i will google and see if I can find more information. thank you for the help though :)